# Making a range macro

Tags: tex-core

Having syntactic sugar for ranges can be useful in programming languages. For example in Ruby, one can use a range by

```rb
(2..10).map {|elem| elem + 1}
```

to get an array consisting of each element in the range added by one (`[3, 4, ..., 11]`).

I've found it helpful to take a look at how things are done in other languages which use Alonzo Church's lambda logic, in this case, Scheme:

```sch
(define (range low high)
  (cond
    [(> low high) null]
    [else (cons low (range (+ low 1) high))]))
```

(I'm assuming that `[...]`-syntax is specific to PLT Scheme. The above is taken from [this webpage](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/17/93442/8657).)

So, recursion, eh? Sure, why not:

```
\def\range#1#2{\ifnum#1>#2\else#1, \range{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}\fi}
\range{2}{10}
\bye
```

Well OK, I get the range (with a surplus comma at the end), but it starts to choke on larger ranges. Why? Looking at the log-file might give a clue with `\tracingmacros=2`:

```
\range #1#2-><macro definition>
#1<-\the \numexpr \the \numexpr \the \numexpr \the \numexpr ...
#2<-10
```

OK, I get the idea.

So I'd need to throw in some `\expandafter`s, right?:

```
\catcode`@=11

\def\R@nge#1#2{\number#1 \ifnum#1<#2, \expandafter\R@nge
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}\fi}

\R@nge{2}{10}
\bye
```

Now it doesn't choke.

I've fallen in love with Alan Jeffrey's `lambda.sty` for lists in TeX's mouth, and so my instinct was to try and make that range into a list:

```
\catcode`@=11
\input lambda.sty
\def\R@nge#1#2{\number#1 \ifnum#1<#2, \expandafter\R@nge
    \expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}%
    \expandafter{\number#2\expandafter}\fi}

\Unlistize{\Listize[\R@nge{2}{10}]} % works, but getting back to the ruby example,

\def\Succ#1{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}

\Unlistize{\Map\Succ{\Listize[\R@nge{2}{10}]}} % doesn't work
% (expected result: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
% instead of: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10+1].)
\bye
```

Maybe those `\expandafter`s are getting back to haunt me at this stage?

So next I tried to follow more strictly the Scheme version:

```
\catcode`@=11
\input lambda.sty
\def\Range#1#2{\TeXif{\ifnum#1>#2}{\Nil}%
  {\Cons{#1}{\Range{\number\numexpr#1+1}{#2}}}}

\Unlistize{\Range{2}{10}}
\bye
```

Looks about the same as the Scheme version, doesn't it? Alas, it returns an empty list!

### The Question

**How can I make a range-macro which would output a list (in the `lambda.sty`-sense) so I can use `\Map` and such with it?**

I have an inkling that the command should somehow resemble the `\Listize`-macro from `lambda.sty`:

```
\def\Listize[#1]%
   {\Listize@#1,\relax]}
\def\Listize@#1,#2]%
   {\TeXif{\ifx\relax#2}%
        {\Singleton{#1}}%
        {\Cons{#1}{\Listize@#2]}}}
```

But I haven't been able to figure out what to change and how.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow all the code snippets; please try and make them full compilable examples.

Comment: @egreg: OK, done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beware (not) terminating numbers!

```
\catcode`@=11
\input lambda.sty
\def\Range[#1..#2]{\TeXif{\ifnum#1>#2 }{\Nil}%
  {\Cons{#1}{\expandafter\Range\expandafter[\number\numexpr#1+1\relax..#2]}}}

\immediate\write20{\Unlistize{\Range[2..10]}}


\bye
```

I added a space after `#2` and a `\relax` after the `\numexpr`

```
$ pdftex ltest2
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011/Cygwin)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ltest2.tex (./lambda.sty)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ltest2.log.
```

Comment: Awesome! Yes, that was IT! Thank you thank you thank you! `:-D`

Comment: Ooh, just a short comment for the reader who is wondering about the `\expandafter`-connection on the "choking-effect": Just put a `\expandafter` before the recursive `\Range` call, and another after it. Makes all the difference. `:-)`

Comment: oops sorry should have noticed that: feel free to edit my answer to your final tested version:-)